# Difference between: SS:DWORD PTR[ESP] & DWORD PTR[ESP]

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly, instruction-set

I was writing inline-assembly to understand memory operations.

But I'm confused about the difference between `SS:DWORD PTR[ESP]` and `DWORD PTR[ESP]`.

What does `SS:` actually mean?

Here is my inline-assembly code in VC++ :

```cpp
    __asm {
        xor eax, eax;
        lea eax, SS:DWORD PTR[ESP];
        // eax is now equals to ESP
        xor eax, eax;
        lea eax, DWORD PTR[ESP];
        // now eax again equals to ESP
    };
```

Comment: `SS:` is pointless in a `LEA` to start with. It's also pointless in a memory access with `[esp]` since that defaults to `SS` anyway. Furthermore, windows uses flat memory so `SS`=`DS` so you never need that override. The `SS:` is frequently seen in broken disassemblers even if the actual code does not use the prefix. TL;DR: don't use it.

Comment: That makes sense thanks.